# Change focus in MATLAB App Designer

Tags: matlab, user-interface, focus, matlab-app-designer

I'm looking for a method to programmatically change the focus to a different panel in the MATLAB App Designer. I have a push-button that I would like to use to shortcut the user to a specific panel in the same UI. My UI is arranged using a series of tab-panels, and I need a way to directly send the user to a different panel.

For normal (non App Designer) MATLAB UI components, I can use the command `uicontrol(itemOfInterest);` to give focus to a particular element of the UI, but this isn't possible with App Designer. Is there a specific command?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that, for what concerns the `App Designer`, as of `Matlab R2017a`, this feature has not been implemented yet. Googling a little bit, I found [this question](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/353504-give-focus-to-an-edit-field), in which the OP basically asks the same. The provided (and accepted) answer is:

> This functionality with "uicontrol" is currently unavailable in App
>   Designer. I have forwarded your feedback to our developers and they
>   will consider adding support for this in a future release of MATLAB.

With a little bit of patience, the focus support will be introduced in a new Matlab release. Meanwhile, I suggest you to do some research focusing on undocumented Matlab features and underlying Java components. With a little bit of luck and [findjobj](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14317-findjobj-find-java-handles-of-matlab-graphic-objects) you could be able to achieve what you are looking for.